# Symfony Unit test Custom Event Listener

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit, symfony-3.3

I have mage my own Event Listener:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventHandlers;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyExceptionListener
{
    /**
    * @var string
    */
    private $env;

    /**
     * @var null|\Twig_Environment
     */
    private $twig=null;

    private $forOfourExceptions=[
      AppBunble\Exceptions\ApiReturnedNoDataException::class,
      AppBunble\Exceptions\DatabaseReturnedNoDataException::class,
      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException::class
    ];

    public function __construct($env,\Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
      $this->env = $env;
      $this->twig=$twig;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // You get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getException();

        $exceptionClass=get_class($exception);

        // Customize your response object to display the exception details
        $response = new Response();

        $content="";
        if(in_array($exceptionClass,ExceptionMapping::RETURN_ERROR_FOUR_HUNDRED_FOUR)){
            $response ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            $content = $this->twig->render('error_404.html.twig');
        } else {
            $response ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

            if($this->env == 'dev'){//Only on production set response
                return;
            }
        }

        $response->setContent($content);

        // Send the modified response object to the event
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

And I did the following Unit Test:

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\EventHandlers;

use AppBundle\Exceptions\ApiReturnedNoDataException;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use AppBundle\EventHandlers\MyExceptionListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class ExceptionListenerTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testnoDataExceptionTest()
    {
        /**
         * @var ExceptionListener
         */
        $class=$this->constructClass();

        $exception=new ApiReturnedNoDataException('giberish');

        $responseEvent=$this->getMockBuilder(GetResponseForExceptionEvent::class)
                                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                ->getMock();

        $responseEvent->method('getException')->willReturn( $exception );

        /**
         * @var Response
         */
        $class->onKernelException($responseEvent);

        $this->assertEquals($response->getStatusCode(),Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    /**
     * @return ExceptionListener
     */
    private function constructClass()
    {

        $twigMock=$this->getMockBuilder(\Twig_Environment::class)
                            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                            ->getMock();

        $twigMock->method('render')->willReturn('');

        $exceptionListener= new ExceptionListener('prod',$twigMock);

        return $exceptionListener;
    }
}
```

But The phpoUnit correctly throws:

```
1) AppBundle\Tests\Managers\ExceptionListenerTest::testnoDataExceptionTest
Error: Call to a member function getStatusCode() on null
```

So I need to construct a correct `GetResponseForExceptionEvent` but its constructor needs to pass an `HttpKernelInterface` inn order to construct it. So:

- Is it advisable to mock the HttpKernelInterface? Will it break the use of the class?
- Is there a better way to unit test the `MyExceptionListener`?

Comment: Where in the test are you setting `$response` from the event that has been sent through the listener?

Comment: For now nowhere I also try to figure out this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tested method takes `GetResponseForExceptionEvent` as argument. This is the class that should be mocked.

Mocking of `HttpKernelInterface` would be acceptable if you were testing `GetResponseForExceptionEvent` class(which is already tested by Symfony developers).

Unit test does not test what happens inside another class, only that your tested class does its job and calls needed methods of other class. This means that testing `MyExceptionListener` is practically asserting that method `setResponse` of `GetResponseForExceptionEvent` is called with correct argument.

Comment: But on mocking will it keep the default methods as is?

Comment: You will mock all the methods that you need yourself. And you will not need any of the others, since you are not running your application, but just a unit test.

Comment: But as you can see it needed the setResponse to be set how can I mock it it returns nothing and affects how `GetResponseForExceptionEvent` works.